# How to change button style depends on width

Tags: wpf, button, resize, controls, visibility

I have simple user control with few controls inside, layout is following:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid
            DockPanel.Dock="Left"
         Margin="25 0 0 2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image
            Grid.Column="0"
            Source="image.png"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="24"
            Height="24" />
            <Label
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="5 0 0 0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                Text="Some text"/>
            </Label>
            <Button
                Grid.Column="2"
                x:Name="SendButton"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="5 0 0 0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image 
                        Width="16" 
                        Height="16" 
                        Margin="2 0"
                        Source="buttonImg1.png"/>
                    <TextBlock 
                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                        Text="Button text1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button
                Grid.Column="3"
                Name="button2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="5 0 0 0">                   
                <TextBlock
                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                    Text="buttonText2"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <CheckBox 
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Margin="0,0,16,0" 
              Grid.RowSpan="2" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                Text="checkbox text"/>
        </CheckBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

So my question is how can I change for instance visibility of TextBlock inside the button when user control resizes so if text inside the TextBlock does not fit inside the button set visibility to collapse to make the button size smaller and when it fit then set it to Visible to return size back to initial? I've tried to bind the TextBlock visibility to the button 
ActualWidth, but when after visibility was set to collapsed, ActualWidth of the button never get bigger during resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" Grid.Column="2">
        <Button
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="16" Height="16" Source="image.png"></Image>
                <TextBlock
                    Padding="20 0 0 0"
                    Text="send request">
                    <TextBlock.Visibility>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="Grid"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="Image"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Visibility>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

converter code:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double gridWidth = double.Parse(values[0].ToString());
        double textBlockWidth = double.Parse(values[1].ToString());
        double imageWidth = double.Parse(values[2].ToString());

        return  gridWidth - textBlockWidth - imageWidth >= 0 
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Grid.Column="2"

```
 <Button Name="SendButton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.Column="2">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Image 
                                                Width="16" 
                                                Height="16" 
                                                Margin="2 0"
                                                Source="buttonImg1.png">
                                                <Image.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=tb1}" Value="Collapsed">
                                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </Image.Style>
                                            </Image>
                                            <TextBlock Name="tb1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                                                Text="Button text1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```